# Interactive mode in Net::OpenSSH

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I am a beginner in perl and trying to write a script that uses Net::OpenSSH to run commands on the given host. How do I do interactive mode auth in Net::OpenSSH similar to what we have in Net:SSH::Perl. Net:SSH::Perl has an interactive flag which takes in password if set to true otherwise public key auth. Following is the ssh object I have in Net::SSH::Perl which I would like to replicate in Net::OpenSSH :

```
 $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host,
                      debug          => $debug,
                      port           => $port,
                      interactive    => $imode,
                      identity_files => [ @keys ],
                      );
```

Also Net::SSH::Perl can take in an array of keys while Net::OpenSSH only one. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) already runs in interactive mode by default, letting the underlaying `ssh` process ask for a password when all the other authentication methods fail (you have to request [`batch_mode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#batch_mode-=%3E-1) to disable it).

You can pass several keys through the [`master_opts`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#master_opts-=%3E-[...]) constructor argument:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, ...
                            master_opts => [map { -i => $_ } @keys]);
```

You can also create a feature request in the GitHub [bug-tracker](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH) and I will eventually add support for accepting more than one key without using the `master_opts` hack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply salva.

Comment: I can only get the password prompt working when I pass the PreferredAuthentications=password option. When I don't it doesn't try to use keyboard input if key auth fails. I am using **0.64** version of the module.

`$ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
        user       => $login,
        key_path      =>  $key,
        master_opts    => [
            '-v'
#            , -o => "PreferredAuthentications=password"
             , -o => "PubkeyAuthentication=no"
        ],
    );`

I want to ssh as a user taken from input.Here's the debug output without any options:

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Comment: @vatsal: that happens because the module disables password authentication when you request public key authentication explicitly (i.e. passing the `key_path` argument).

Comment: Is there a way to override that? Let's say if the key fails it falls back to password authentication?

Comment: @vatsal: that isn't directly supported by the module but again the `master_opts` ctor argument provides a direct access to the underlaying `ssh` process command line. For your particular case, just pass the public key path: `master_opts => [-i => $key_path]`

Comment: How do I disable buffering when running commands? Right now the output only shows when the command fired exits.

Comment: I'm using 0.64 version of the module